# Store config settings for a .NET DLL (not EXE or Web)

Tags: .net, asp.net, configuration, web-config, app-config

I have a .NET 4 class library project, which is used by multiple web projects. In this class library I need to get a DB connection string and it needs to be the same for all the web projects. Currently I've got it as a setting in each **web.config** file, but this is not ideal. Is there any way I can have that configuration stored with the DLL, but still allow it to be modified at runtime (ie. hardcoding the connection string is out)?

App.config seems to be generally ignored for a DLL, even though it does get renamed to *assemblyname*.dll.config and copied to the **bin** directory for the web. I tried making it an "application setting" (ie. using the auto-generated class derived from `System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase`) and this *appeared* to work, but changing the value in the DLL .config file at runtime had no effect, so I suspect it's really just using the hardcoded *default value* of the setting.

Comment: since a dll is always used in a application (exe or web), why can't you store the configuration in the application's config-file?

Comment: I can and that's what I currently do, but I have to store the same value in 5 places.

Comment: 5 different places because... you have 5 different applications !?

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned in the original question, I have multiple Web projects using that DLL.

Comment: its a coincidence that each of your 5 applications share the same connection string, and cannot be any of your dll-files concern. Christian.K gives a good answer about the "passiveness" of a dll, and that it is each application that is using the dlls responsibility to provide the necessary configuration.

Comment: Ok, I had the exact same issue. I have a dll where I want to store loads of settings. I have a UI front end for testing and a task .exe file that calls it - I guess this is why I wanted to put the config file in the dll to avoid copying it to each "UI" or interface that uses it, but these answers make sense..

Answer (score 2):

You can store the setting in the Registry Database if it should be the same for all programs on the machine using your library.

Comment: @Pauli: -1 for suggesting the Registry. Wow.

Comment: what do you you actually think the Registry Database is for...?

Comment: +1, not because I think it is a particularly good idea, but to not make this answer look to bad due to the downvote above. I think the registry is sometimes frowned upon without good reason. Certainly it has its issues, especially concerning locality and discoverablity of application settings (or xcopy-deployment). However, if you have the technical need to store values in a central place, it is IMHO at least as sound as using a *central* configuration file (however you read it then from your DLL code).

Comment: @John tell that to the thousands of developers, including Microsoft them selves, that uses the registry database. Don't downvote because of personal bias.

Comment: @Pauli: downvoted because the registry isn't the place to store .NET configuration settings. That's what the Settings file is for.

Comment: if you need a library-specific setting that should be the SAME for ALL applications using this library, the registry is what you would go for. I would hardly consider a connection string being such a .Net specific setting, unless you need to reference the connectionString node from elsewhere in the web.config.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I would do that (even if you somehow manage to get it to work, and yes the built-in configuration mechanism won't let you). I would always store behavioral settings of an application *with* the application's own configuration. I have done and seen systems where such values were stored in a database - which is of course not very feasible for a connection string.

A DLL as such is passive (or should be) and only acts upon explicit calls from its users, and thus should not need any configuration for its own purpose (except may "global" diagnostics stuff, but even then...), as the caller can provide it when or before using the respective functionality.

If you have multiple applications that incidentally require the same settings, then this is nothing the DLL should know or even care about.

To make things more manageable, you might consider relocating this issue into the build or deployment process instead. In your application configuration files (web.config files for that matter) put a placeholder for the connectionstring. Then during build or deployment (whatever suits your needs better) replace that placeholder with the true connection string, which you can keep in a single file.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to change this. This is just how .NET works. You have to copy the settings from the DLL app.config to the web.config or *programName*.exe.config file.